# Java, Linked List of Item objects. How to refer to the current item?

Tags: java, abstract

I have a class which holds a linked list of Item objects. I want this class to hold the "current" Item somehow so I can refer to it in other parts of the program. Is the best way to do this to create a Item object within my class and set it equal to the "current" Item when I wish to set it?

as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [LinkedListofItems].length(); i++)
    {Item currentItem = [LinkedListofItems].getAt(i); break;}
```

And then if I would like to set and Items attributes equal to anothers I would override the = operator?

Comment: Implement an `Iterator`.

Comment: May I ask why you are using a LinkedList? They are much slower for iteration. If they are in no particular order, I would suggest an ArrayList if you will be accessing them frequently

Comment: My eyes hurt with your code example... Please **use an iterator** or the enhanced `for-loop` syntax (if you're using Java SE 5+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement an iterator on the LinkedList.

```
Iterator listIterator = LinkedListOfItems.iterator();
//Use iterator here to access a particular list element by calling .next()
Item itemToStore = listIterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

A) From your code example and from what you asked, they seem to be saying two different things. First I would suggest an ArrayList if you will be needing to iterate frequently and if you are **not** adding and deleting a lot from said list.

B) I am also unsure why you are iterating from your example. If you have an Item that needs to be set for I, you can just use elementAt() method.

C) Also, you must implement an Iterator to traverse the list.

```
Iterator linkedListIt = LinkedList.iterator();
```

Now you can go through and what you need, and grab the current object if you need with LinkedList.next();

Comment: My example was just to show that I want to set an Item object to a item in my list, I know terrible example, to many comments on how bad it is to change it, would make this post even worse.